# Generate IP list from text file

Tags: php, list, ip, generate

i have text file contains IP range like this format ::

```
52.0.0.0-52.1.255.255
52.5.0.0-52.50.255.255
```

i want to Generate IP list from this range , line by line 
i try to do that by using this code but its not working .

```
<?php

$file = file('ips.txt');
foreach ($file AS $line) {
    $ips = explode('-', $line);
    $range_one = $ips[0];
    $range_two = $ips[1];

    $ip1 = ip2long ($range_one);
    $ip2 = ip2long ($range_two);
    while ($ip1 <= $ip2) {
    print_r (long2ip($ip1) ."". "\n");
    $ip1 ++;

}
}
?>
```

and i want to save the output at txt file , 
Please help to do that and correct the mistake if i have .

Comment: You get an error? What happens? Maybe replace `print_r` with `$str .=` then write that to a file?

Comment: Code in **foreach loop** is fine. Do you forget to remove "\n" in **$line**

Answer (score 1):

Add code to remove *\r\n* or *\n* in each line be for explode *'-'*

And also save output to text file.

```
<?php

$file = file('ips.txt');
$data = "";
foreach ($file AS $line) {

    $ip_range = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$line); /* remove \r\n or \n before explode '-' */

    $ips = explode('-', $ip_range);
    $range_one = $ips[0];
    $range_two = $ips[1];

    $ip1 = ip2long ($range_one);
    $ip2 = ip2long ($range_two);

    while ($ip1 <= $ip2) {
        $data .= (long2ip($ip1) ."". "\n"); /* save each line to string */
        $ip1 ++;
    }
}

print_r ($data);
file_put_contents("ips_list.txt", $data); /* save output to text file */

?>
```

Comment: thanks , but it dose not work output file is empty .:(